# A question with an odd hypothesis.

Tags: commutative-algebra, field-theory, modules

Let $S$ be a discrete valuation ring and $R\subset S$ be a proper subring (also a DVR).  Assuming that $M$ and $N$ are the respective maximal ideals of $R$ and $S$ and that $N\cap R = M$, then the quotient field of $S$ is a proper subfield of the quotient field of $R$.

My Idea:  Take $x\in S - R$ which must be non-zero.  Then $(x)$ is an ideal of $S$.  Since $(x)\neq 0$ and $S$ is a discrete valuation ring, then we must have that $(x)$ is an ideal of $S$.

I know this doesn't go very far, but there are a few hypothesis that are bizarre to me.

The requirement that $N\cap R = M$ sounds a bit like the requirements of the "going up" theorem [of which there seems to be quite a few versions :(] but since $R$ is integrally closed, $S$ cannot be integral over $R$.  So this is paragraph I have all but completely dismissed.

To complete the story, I am stuck.

Comment: The first paragraph is a question and the rest is what you've tried, if I got it well? It is not obvious from the question.

Comment: Yep!  That's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are implicitly assuming that $R$ is also a DVR, so I will also use this.

Assume the fraction fields of $R$ and $S$ are equal:  $R\subseteq S\subseteq \text{Frac}(R)$. Let $0\neq a\in S$, we want to show that $a\in R$: If $v_R(a)\geq 0$ we're done, so assume $v_R(a)<0$, which implies $v_R(a^{-1})>0$ and so $a^{-1}\in M\subseteq N$, but that is impossible as $a\in S\Rightarrow a^{-1}\notin N$.

We have shown that all $a\in S $ satisfy $v_R(a)\geq 0$ and so $R=S$.

**EDIT**: In fact it is enough to assume that $R$ and $S$ are [valuation rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_domain).

Assume the fraction fields of $R$ and $S$ are equal. Take $a\in S\backslash R$. Since $R$ is a valuation ring $a^{-1}\in R$, but $a^{-1}$ is not a unit in $R$ and hence is in the maximal ideal $M$ of $R$. $a^{-1}\in M\subseteq N\subseteq S$. This is a contradiction, as $a^{-1}\in N$ implies that $a^{-1}$ is not a unit in $S$ and hence $a\notin S$.

Comment: Thanks so much.  You are indeed correct about my mistake.

So whenever we are dealing with a DVR is it true that we are entitled to a discrete valuation map $v_{R}$?

Comment: @borninthe80s: In fact I took this as a definition of a DVR, but there is a long list of equivalent definitions, see [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_valuation_ring). 
Actually the use of a discrete valuation hides what is really going on. Please see my edit for a clearer and more general solution.

Comment: @borninthe80s: Also, you might not know, but it makes this page more organised if you mark correct answers by ticking the symbol under the vote buttons.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up.  I usually don't check the answer until I've successfully worked through it.  But I do always accept a correct answer when this happens.  And I've no doubt that your answer is correct.  (In the meantime I certainly upvoted it.  I hope this is OK.)

Comment: By "check" I mean mark as correct.

Comment: @borninthe80s: Sorry, of course that's OK :)

Comment: No need to be sorry.  You've laid this out in a very basic way.  I should be able to follow it immediately.  The only thing slowing me down is that we were given a different definition of a DVR, so in order to use your argument, I first must prove the equivalent of definitions (which a peer of mine says is possible with a couple of theorems we proved in class, thankfully).

To clarify: me not yet checking the answer in no way means that I don't accept/believe/trust it.  I just have to catch up.  :)